# Include exam questions in another documentclass

Tags: questionnaire

I would like to use sone of CTAN exam.cls environments like questions, solution, parts in another documentclass. Can I extract only some enviroments from a class? Do you know any package that would have the same functionalities?

Comment: You might want to give the packages [`xsim`](https://ctan.org/pkg/xsim) or [`eqexam`](https://ctan.org/pkg/eqexam) a try.

Comment: No one hinders you to copy some lines of code out of the .cls file. But be aware that making it work might need a while (the code might depend on other macros which you didn't copy over). In general I guess your better of using a package which is designed for this.